# How to handle error in asp.net Httphandler?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I have Httphandler in asp.net that return a file. In code I have  `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=somefile.ext");` so the page URL remains unchanged. 
But in case of error in Httphandler URL become some thing like this `http://localhost:55161/document.axd` and I have white screen.

How I can  return, for example, javascript alert from Httphandler without page refresh? Something like this:

```
public class Document: IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest Request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse Response = context.Response;

        //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=somefile.ext");
        Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
        Response.Write("<script type ='text/javascript'>alert('Error!');</script>");

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

PS sorry for my english, I am not native speaker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing it wrongly. You shouldn't return javascript from http handler. They are meant to be used to process data. The alert should be shown based on the result of the Httphandler execution.

What you can do is put try catch blocks in your http handler, and return specific code as a result if there is an exception. Then in your javascript - check for that code - and show an alert.

Down you can find something that I have used in this cases. It will give you an idea- you have a separate class which contain the result of the execution - and return JSON that is easy to process by javascript.

```
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var result = new HandlerResult();
            var resultJson = string.Empty;
            var reqDictionary = Helper.DecryptQueryParams(context);

            try
            {
                if (!Helper.AllQueryParametersExists(reqDictionary, "userid", "topN", "time", "latitude", "logitude", "shareLocation"))
                {
                    _log.Error("Incomplete query string parameters!");

                    throw new Exception("Incomplete query string parameters!");
                }

                Guid userId;
                Guid.TryParse(reqDictionary["userid"], out userId);
                int topN;
                int.TryParse(reqDictionary["topn"], out topN);

                double minutes;
                double.TryParse(reqDictionary["time"], out minutes);

                var time = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-minutes);

                double latitude;
                double.TryParse(reqDictionary["latitude"], out latitude);
                double logitude;
                double.TryParse(reqDictionary["logitude"], out logitude);
                bool shareLocation = Helper.ParseInt(reqDictionary["sharelocation"]);

                var finalTime = new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, time.Day, time.Hour, time.Minute, 0);

                var users = _userAccessor.Repo.FindUsers(userId, topN, finalTime, latitude,
                    logitude, shareLocation);

                var sb = new StringBuilder();

                var list = new List<UserLocation>();
                foreach (var user in users)
                {
                    var userLocation = new UserLocation
                    {
                        UserId = user.Id,
                        UserName = user.Email,
                        FullName = user.FullName,
                        Gender = user.Gender,
                        Age = user.Age,
                        Latitude = user.Latitude,
                        Longitude = user.Longitude,
                        Time = user.Time
                    };

                    list.Add(userLocation);
                }

                context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());


                result.Result = string.Empty;
                result.ResultStatus = HandlerResult.Status.Successful;
                resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
                _log.Info("OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.ResultStatus = HandlerResult.Status.Error;
                result.Result = ex.Message;
                resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
                _log.Error(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write(resultJson);
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.End();

                _log.Info(resultJson);
            }
        }


   public class HandlerResult
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }

        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        public Status ResultStatus { get; set; }

        public HandlerResult(Status resultStatus, string result)
        {
            this.ResultStatus = resultStatus;
            this.Result = result;
        }

        public HandlerResult(string result)
        {
            ResultStatus = Status.Novalue;
            this.Result = result;
        }

        public HandlerResult()
        {

        }

        public enum Status
        {
            Novalue = 0,
            Successful = 1,
            Error = 2,
            Notvaliduser = 3,
            Successfulupdate = 4,
            UserExists = 5,
            UserNotConfirmed = 6
        }
    }
```